# Random с определенной вероятностью появления

Tags: php, случайные-числа

Есть `randon(1,10);` Можно ли реализовать его с неким процентом то есть всё тот же рандом, но у 2-ки шанс выпасть 80% и т.п.

У кого нибудь есть идеи?

Comment: А если например сделать random от 1 до  20 и например  сделать  что цифры 2, 1,3,4, 8, 9,10, 17 ,18 из рандома равны 1, а цифры 5,7 11,13,14,15,16,19,20 равны 2 и только цифра 12 равна 3

Comment: @NetSperes ровно 80% так просто не получится. и функция довольно сложная у вас получилась.

Answer (score 9):

Для решения Вашей задачи, существуют следующие методы:

- Аналитический;
- Табличный;
- Метод композиций (не буду рассматривать, так как его применяют при получении распределений по закону Эрланга или гиреэкспоненциальному).

---

**Аналитический метод**  - суть заключается в подстановки значения генератора случайных чисел в некоторую функцию. Для нахождения функции необходимо решить уравнение *F(x) = s*, где *F(x)* – Ваше распределение, *s* – значение генератора случайных чисел.

Для примера, возьмём экспоненциальное распределение:

[image]

В пункте 2 логарифмируем выражение. Выражения 3 и 4 эквиваленты с точки зрения теории вероятностей, поскольку случайные величины s и (1-s) распределены по одному и тому же равномерному закону в интервале (0;1).

***Преимущества***

- Высокая точность;
- Не требуется память под хранение таблицы (в отличие от табличного метода).

***Недостатки***

- Требует много вычислительных ресурсов (логарифм раскладывается в ряд);
- Применим только для функций, у которых можно вычислить интеграл аналитически.

---

**Табличный метод** – заключается в формировании таблицы содержащий пары чисел: значение функции распределения генератора случайных чисел и соответствующее ему значение. Значения между узлами обычно рассчитывается линейной интерполяцией.

Пример таблицы для экспоненциального распределения с математическим ожиданием 1.

[image]

***Преимущества***

- Можно построить таблицу для формирования любого закона распределения;
- Можно обеспечить любую точность;
- Мало процессорного времени тратится на обработку.

***Недостатки***

- Затраты памяти на хранение таблицы;
- Наличие погрешности, в результате применения линейной интерполяции;
- В некоторых отрезках, функция может резко изменяться, вследствие чего необходимо подбирать оптимальный шаг.

Всё выше сказанное - переработанная информация из книги Т.И. Алиев [Основы моделирования дискретных систем](http://books.ifmo.ru/book/445/book_445.htm), раздел 6.2.3.

Comment: код покажите? по первому методу очень интересно (про второй @Равнодушный написал)

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой вариант - создаем массив, в котором 80% элементов - "2", 1% - "1", ..., и т.д., перемешиваем его и берем первый элемент или не перемешиваем и берем случайный.
Хотя есть и более рациональные решения для каждой конкретной ситуации.

Comment: можно ещё экспоненциальную функцию подобрать, чтобы результаты рандома сдвигать в ту или иную сторону

Answer (score 2):

"и т.п." наводит на мысль, что не только двойка имеет свою вероятность.

1. Создаете массив вероятностей на ваш диапазон
2. Получаете случайное значение от 0 до суммы вероятностей
3. Идете по списку вероятностей, вычитая вероятности из полученного в п.2 случайного числа
4. Если разность стала отрицательной значит индекс и будет вашим случайным числом с указанной вероятностью выпадения.

Вот [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/ivanovsuper/7ajgy/3/) на javascript'е, конкретно функция `RandomP`.

ЗЫ Для случая когда "только 2-ка выпадает в 80% случаев" можно массив не использовать, достаточно одного `if`'а. Интервал просто расширить и "все что больше N - это двойка", останется рассчитать N и все.

Answer (score 2):

На коленке:

```
if (rand(1, 100) < 80) { // 80% случаев
  return 2;
} else { // оставшиеся 20%
  while (($r = rand(1, 10)) == 2) {}; // ждем рандома != 2
  return $r;
}
```

Comment: по мотивам, чтобы без цикла: (можно и без второго rand обойтись, но тут надо смотреть, что дороже)

    if ($r=rand(1, 100) < 80) return 2  // 80% случаев
     //else не надо
    if (($r = rand(1, 9)) < 2) return $r; //1 
    return ($r+1);

Comment: @eicto, плюс, только присвоения первый раз тоже не надо)

Comment: это я хотел сначала оставшиеся 20% распределить между 1-9 а потом заломало :) [вот так](http://ideone.com/pNc7BV)

Comment: вот так еще короче:

    $r = rand(1,45); return $r>10?2:$r;

Answer (score 1):

Общий метод решения такой задачи следующий:

1. Задаем некую функцию плотности вероятности `y=f(x)`, где `x` - интервал в котором генерируется случайная величина, `у` - плотность вероятности - то есть с какой частотой будет выпадать заданный `x`. Функция может быть сколь угодно сложной - это надеюсь понятно. В классическом варианте при обработке экспериментальных данных это т.н. [шапка Гаусса](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CD%EE%F0%EC%E0%EB%FC%ED%EE%E5_%F0%E0%F1%EF%F0%E5%E4%E5%EB%E5%ED%E8%E5)
2. Генерируем `x` - допустим выпала 2-ка. Вычисляем `у=f(2)` получаем 0.8
3. Генерируем далее `x[i]` а значения соответствующих `y[i]` копим, но копим так, что как только значение `y[i]` станет больше 1 - говорим выкинули число x[i]

В общем как-то так.

Answer (score 0):

масив из N-го количеста чисел, рандом генерирует число N и выдирает число из масива под индексом N, при это нужно учитывать что масив начинаестя из числа '0', допустим у нас есть числа 1, 2, 3, 4 и 5, нам надо что бы у числа 2 была вероятность 50%, делаем масив из 100 символов (можно сколько угодно), дальше 50 значений нашего масива должно состоять из числа 2 а все остальные значения из 1, 3, 4 и 5, потом функция генерирующая рандомные числа от 0 до 99 (так как масив начинается с индекса 0) и мы вытягиваем число из масива под сгенерированым индексом. надеюсь кто-то оценит идею