# Вывести из базы 1 строку с шансом

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть такой запрос

```
SELECT * FROM `prizes` WHERE `caseid` = '{$id}' AND `winner` = '0' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Я получаю рандомный приз из базы, но есть проблема, при выдачи выдается рандом полный, т.е может 4 раза подряд выпасть дорогой приз а дешевый нет. Я добавил в таблицу параметр **`chance`** подскажите как мне получить так-же 1 строку из базы но уже сделать выборку не только рандомно но и по шансу.
Шанс до 100, т.е если указано 90 выпадает чаще чем если указано 89 и наоборот.
Если указано 10 выпадает реже если указано 90 но выпасть может.

В базе 11 тысяч призов.

Answer (score 0):

1 За ORDER BY RAND() Вам могут отрубить руки, насколько я знаю.. 
Просто получите все элементы в переменную, а затем выбирайте рандомный приз средствами другого языка - сэкономите запросы.

2 Как раз с помощью серверного языка можно реализовать задуманное Вами. Допустим, м два этапа. Но рандом на то и рандом, что выбирает рандомно.
[Вот здесь подобный вопрос был](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/233711/random-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: Сказать легче чем сделать ;( я не асс программирование и не знаю все языки мира как вы а всего один.

Comment: Ныть легче, чем пытаться. Пробуйте, что не будет получаться - спрашивайте.